# not applicable for the arguments azure

Tags: android, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

> The method delete(Object, TableDeleteCallback) in the type
>   MobileServiceTableBase is not applicable for
>   the arguments (JsonObject, List>, new
>   TableDeleteCallback(){})

Error code above. Trying to create or delete blob containers from android app

```
    public void deleteBlob(final String containerName, String blobName) {
    //Create the json Object we'll send over and fill it with the required
    //id property - otherwise we'll get kicked back
    JsonObject blob = new JsonObject();     
    blob.addProperty("id", 0);
    //Create parameters to pass in the blob details.  We do this with params
    //because it would be stripped out if we put it on the blob object
    List<Pair<String,String>> parameters = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
    parameters.add(new Pair<String, String>("containerName", containerName));
    parameters.add(new Pair<String, String>("blobName", blobName));     
    mTableBlobs.delete(blob, parameters, new TableDeleteCallback() {            
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, exception.getCause().getMessage());
                return;
            }
            //Refetch the blobs from the server
            getBlobsForContainer(containerName);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the `delete()` method should be called with 2 arguments, and you're passing 3, this is why it doesn't compile.